# MSVCP110D.dll and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run a program I compiled in Visual Studio 2013. However, I get the error

```
The program can't start because MSVCP110D.dll is missing from
your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

This is not a very helpful error. However, after some Googling, I found that it is (apparently) trying to load a standard `c++` library dynamically, and that to get around this I need to specify the `/MT` option rather than the `/MD` option. This leaves me with a number of questions:

1. What exactly is that doing?
2. What are the benefits of `/MD` as opposed to `/MT`? I mean, there must be a reason that it is the default options...
3. How would I go about getting the looked for `.dll` and getting Visual Studio to use it? I downloaded [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39315), but honestly don't know exactly how to use it.
4. Most importantly, how to I get that error to go away and my program to run?

Some additional info: I am compiling in `Release` mode using an `x64` build.

Comment: MSVCP110D.dll is a debug dll from Visual Studio 2012 (unless 2013 also kept the same dlls).

Comment: The project WAS originally built with VS2012. Why is it still being looked for now?

Comment: You will not find this dll in a redistributable since debug dlls are not redistributable.

Comment: Did you do a clean build?

Comment: Yes. Quite a number of them, actually.

Comment: How about deleting the Debug and Release folder? Also are there any other outside dependencies that you are linking your application to?

Comment: You are getting this problem in release mode? Something is very wrong.

Comment: Yes. I am linking to the Qt library. I tried deleting my Debug and Release folders, but that did nothing.

Comment: Did you build Qt using Visual Studio 2013? You can not use the Visual Studio 2012 version.

Comment: I built Qt using VS2012. I will build it using VS2013 and see what happens. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I think @drescherjm described the problem right.  You need to build both your app and all libraries it uses, using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing different versions of Visual Studio by using Qt that was compiled using a different compiler. Remember that each version of Visual Studio will have its own runtime/CRT. The Qt dlls that were compiled with Visual Studio 2012 and will be dependent on the Visual Studio 2012 runtime. They will not use the 2013 runtime.

The solution to this problem is to recompile all of your code and dependent libraries/dlls with the same compiler.

**Warning:**
Some users will try to just install the dynamic runtime (or recompile dependent libraries with static CRT) from the other version of Visual Studio however this is not a solution to this problem mainly because each runtime has its own independent heap. Having separate heaps can and will lead to random crashes caused by allocating memory in one heap and then trying to free it in a different heap. Since the heaps do not share information about allocations or deallocations this leads to having corrupt heaps. From my experience the problem does not always cause an instant crash. The crash may or may not happen on the next allocation of the corrupt heap so debugging this situation can be very frustrating.