# MSVCP120d.dll not found error while using the QT Library

Tags: c++, qt, msvc12

Hey guys I am trying to use QT for my project and I downloaded the 5.2.1 msvc2012_64 version of QT.

However, I am getting an MSVCP120d.dll error while trying to run an exe file. I understand that it is caused by having Visual Studio 2013 libraries in the project. The problem was indeed caused by using the 5.2.1 version of QT as disabling QT seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2013 installed? Remember that the MSVCP120d.dll requires you to have Visual Studio 2013 installed. If you are using Visual Studio 2012 you need a version of Qt compiled with Visual Studio 2012. This is not the correct one.

Comment: I really wonder how you can use Qt in your project with Qt being disabled?! The dll mentioned is as stated part of the VS-2012, which is required for linking "debug"-enabled Qt-applications/libraries. Since you have vs-2013 think about downloading a version linked against the 2013 version or install vs2012 express to get a copy of the dll required.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 and do not have vs2013 installed. I obtained qt msvc2012_64 via the online installer.I assumed qt5.1.2 msvc 2012_64 is a library for visual studio 2012.

Comment: I disabled qt by removing or dll/lib links to qp from the project.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any other Qt libs/dlls in addition to the official Qt sources? I would not expect the official Qt binaries to be wrong (if they are a bug report should be created).

Comment: Also I don't remember the binary installer (I always build Qt from source) does it have 2 digit VS versions or 4 digit. I ask this because Visual Studio 2012 = vc11 and Visual Studio 2013 = vc12. See the confusion.. This is why Visual Studio 2013 has libraries named `MSVCP120d.dll`

Comment: I am linking Qtcored.dll and Qt5Widgetsd.lib which are both from the msvc2012_64, using dlls provided by msvc2012_64.. I am trying to compile from source right now which takes ages

Comment: I previously discussed the Visual Studio versions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707992/msvcp120d-dll-missing/21730219#21730219 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950479/msvcp110d-dll-and-visual-studio-2013/19860574#19860574

Comment: I would file a bug report with Qt because the dlls should not require Visual Studio 2013 runtimes / crt. This is a bug.

Comment: yep I understand that msvcp120d.dll not found error is caused by a lib/dll compiled by visual studio 2013, however the downloaded qt library states that its a msvc2012, hence would only require msvcp110d.dll, odd that it requests for a msvcp120d.dll