# Visual Studio 2013 generated solution from CMake links VS 2012 libraries

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker, cmake, cmake-gui

I generate a Visual Studio 2013 solution using CMake 3.0.2. When compiled it gives errors similar to this:

[MSVCP110D.dll and Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950479/msvcp110d-dll-and-visual-studio-2013)

I can't get my head around this, the toolset is v120 so why does it link v110 libraries? I've asked in the CMake IRC channel but they can't help me. It's impossible to debug the program because the redistributable does not include debugging dlls.

Edit: This is an Ogre3D application that i derived from the tutorials cmake zip. I've barely touched the CMakeLists.txt, only set REQUIRED for finding boost and added boost-system to libraries that are copied during install.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  You say similar errors, are they similarly or exactly the same?  What does your project consist of?  Are you trying to use pre-compiled libraries?  What does your CMakeLists.txt look like (post it if possible).  As currently written there isn't enough information in your question to provide any help.

Comment: CMake links with the libraries that it finds. To avoid problems I create a completely different build tree for each compiler version and 32/64 bit and use some scripting and environment variables (each tree has its own environment / cmake-gui is launched in a cmd.exe window the first time for each package) to force CMake to find packages only inside of the build tree that I am using. The source is in a different tree and shared between all compilers.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. The similarity is the error message, but I am not using Qt which I assume is the toolkit for KDE apps. My project is an Ogre3D game, the CMakeLists.txt is almost identical to what the tutorial cmake zip consists of, I just have REQUIRED when it looks for Boost.

Comment: An Ogre-person says it's probably because I use Ogre3D with prebuilt libraries, built with VS 2012. So I'm going to try to build it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution regarding the Ogre3D-specific issues with this. The latest prebuilt 1.9 package was compiled with VS11 (2012) so that's why the .dll is missing, since I use VS12 (2013) as IDE.
The solution is to build Ogre3D from source, as is explained in depth here: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Building+Ogre

Remember to update your OGRE_HOME environment variable to point at the *sdk* folder inside the build.

Hope this helps other lost souls!